# What's the meaning of tmax of the control parameter in optim of R?

Tags: r, optimization

I'm new to R and data mining/ machine learning.

I'm trying to understand the use of `optim` with SANN method.

I found the documentation of the parameter `tmax` as follows:

```
tmax
    is the number of function evaluations at each temperature for the "SANN" method. Defaults to 10.
```

What does that suppose to mean ?

In my understanding of SANN, you just need to come up with one candidate solution at each temperature. So I don't know what does this `tmax` means. Does it mean you can try up to`tmax`candidates and then choose the best one to proceed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try making the temperature function listed in the documentation into an R function so you can experiment:

```
tf <- function(t,temp,tmax) temp / log(((t-1) %/% tmax)*tmax + exp(1))
curve(tf(x,temp=10,tmax=10),from=1,to=1000)
curve(tf(x,temp=10,tmax=100),col=2,add=TRUE)
curve(tf(x,temp=10,tmax=5),col=4,add=TRUE)
```

(Bottom line: yes, `tmax` keeps the temperature fixed at a specified temperature for longer. You don't choose the best option from each temperature -- rather, at each step you pick a candidate option and compare it to the previously kept option according to the simulated annealing (Metropolis) rule ...)

[image: temperature curves]

Comment: Thanks Ben, does that means: with higher tmax, I can choose from more candidates in each temperature using simulated annleaing rule, but the next temperature will be lower than that of smaller tmax ?

Comment: I don't quite understand the second half of the question. `tmax` affects (only) the length of time spent at each temperature.  If you look at the figure you see that the underlying temperature curve is the same, it's just a question of how granular/coarse the temperature steps are.